# return statement shows XSS vulnerability in Asp.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xss, veracode

This is the code snippet:

```
public static string IntendedAction(UrlHelper url, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null) {
    if (url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url == null) return null;
        var scheme = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;
        return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
    }
```

```
return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
```

Where the security issue occurs?

Comment: Why do you think there is a XSS vulnerability? How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: did a veracode scan and it showed a few vulnerabilities

Comment: Include the relevant veracode scan information in your question

Comment: Description of the vulnerability: "CWE 80 Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)"

Comment: Post the rendered HTML in suspect.